# How to play music from playlist tag?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to play music dynamically from playlist by click.

**Simple Player**

```
<audio id="play" controls="controls">
    <source src="music/song.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
                    </audio>
```

**Playlist**

```
    <ol>
    <?php if($lists) { foreach ($lists as $key=> $list) { ?>
       <li class="click">
    <a href="#" src="music/<?php  echo $list;  ?>.mp3">
<?php  echo $list;  ?>   </a>
     </li>
        <?php }}?>
    </ol>
```

Need javascript function to play dynamically all songs continually.